# Typescript: is it true that there is no difference between { [key: string]: any } and { [key: number]: any}?

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript and I found something weird in the language. I wrote the following code and surprisingly it compiles and runs:

```
let x: { [key: string]: any } = {'hi': 'bye'}
let y: { [key: number]: any} = x;
```

[link to Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=34&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBDeEDaBrEBPOBnMAnAlgHYDmAunAIaHoQC%20EAvAgOQAW%20zczARuiM7QCwAKFCRMCZGgmEArgFtuIXOQhV09JlADcIgMYB7QlgOgAdMAPEAFOgCUQA)

How does it make sense that the object {'hi': 'bye'} is assigned to a variable of type {[key: number]: any}? The key, 'hi', is not a number.

Comment: Technically? Yes, the number key will be translated to a string one, so the number one is compatible with the string one. Given that the string variant is a superset of the number variation, it will accept one an other...

Comment: You're always allowed to have more properties than those mentioned in a type.  Excess properties (like `"hi"`) are not generally prohibited, except for when you assign an object literal, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQJlAN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer (or find an appropriate duplicate source).  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz I don't understand why "hi" is an excess property. key: number is declared explicitly in the type { [key: number]: any }. I think that it says that the key must be a number.

Comment: Index signatures like `{[key: K]: V}` don't mean "all keys must be of type `K` ".  They mean "*if* a key is of type `K` then the property must be of type `V`".  A numeric index signature makes no mention about a key named `"hi`" one way or another.  If I add a key named `"hi"` to an object assigned to a type with only a numeric index signature, then `"hi" is merely an *excess property*.  Does that make sense now or am I still missing something?

Comment: @jcalz now it does

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `{ [key: string]: any }` and `{ [key: number]: any }`, as they specify different key sets.  But just because you can assign `y = x` it does not mean that the types of those variables are the same.  It just means they are "compatible" or "assignable".  If you can assign `x = y`, then we say `y` is assignable to `x` (or `typeof y` is assignable to `typeof x`).  Often this is the same as saying that `y` is a [subtype] of `x`.  So therefore `{ [key: string]: any }` is assignable to `{ [key: number]: any }`.  But why?  What does `{ [k: K]: V }` mean?

---

An [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) of the form `{[k: K]: V}` does not imply that *every* property key must be of type `K`.  It just means that if you have a key which *is* of type `K`, then the value must be of type `V`.  It makes no mention at all of what should or should not happen for keys of a type other than `K`.  And TypeScript's [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) generally permits such "extra" or "excess" properties, [except for certain situations involving object literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks).

So all `{ [key: number]: any}` means is that every property key of type `number`<sup>*</sup> will have a property value of type [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  You will be allowed to index into such an object with any numeric key.  It does *not* say anything about a key like `"hi"`.  And as such, it is possible that an object of this type might have a `"hi"` key.  The following assignment therefore succeeds:

```
let x: { [key: string]: any } = { 'hi': 'bye' };
let y: { [key: number]: any } = x; // okay
```

Even after such an assignment, though, the compiler will complain if you try to index into `y` with a non-`number` key, because the type of `y` has no idea what might be at such a key:

```
y[1]; // okay
y.hi; // error
```

And if you try to assign `{hi: "bye"}` as an object literal directly to `y`, it will also fail, because it runs afoul of the excess property checking:

```
y = { 'hi': 'bye' }; // error;
```

That failure doesn't mean `{hi: "bye"}` is an invalid value for the type of `y` (after all, `y = x` is accepted).  It just means it's likely to be an error because after you assign `y = { hi: "bye" }`, the compiler will not let you access the `hi` key (as shown above with `y.hi` being an error), so the compiler has essentially completely forgotten about the `hi` key, and that's probably a developer mistake.  `y = x` doesn't have this problem because `x` still provides access to the `hi` key.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBDeEDaBrEBPOBnMAnAlgHYDmAunAIaHoQC+EAvAhAOQAW+LcLARuiCzoBYAFBQkARlIBuCAHo5EAPYoK6UVAB0HWQuWr1I0aEiZmqDHEIBXALY8QuchCo16TKLsUq1o9JJl5bwM-bXwvCEdcJVw-RmZ2Tm4+AToIqJjZUSA)

---

<sup><sup>*</sup> Actually there are no keys of type `number` in JavaScript; instead there are numeric strings like `"0"` and `"1"`.  TypeScript pretends that they are numbers because it's very convenient to iterate over arrays with numeric indices.</sup>