# How to transform a number type into a string type?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface Endpoints {
  [k: string]: any
}
type UseXQueryPattern<E extends string> = `use${Capitalize<E>}Query`
interface QueryHooks {
  [key: UseXQueryPattern<keyof Endpoints>]: any
}
```

Compiling this code gives the following error:

```
Type 'string | number' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2344)
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIgCYAcD2owDOyA3gFDLIDaA1gFzIFhSgDmAuvXCAJ6kC+pMNywoAqgQgANAIoBXaNwAKcMJCggAPKmQQAHpExFGzECwB8yALzIABrIkASYgGE4WYGDgAbYAC8IWmZ8cgo2pPjQ8EjIIVDcABI4ONREZBQ0ENz04lKxSipqmtSZODBomLj4BGYcyFy8AkA)

Even though I am explicitly saying in the `Endpoints` interface that `[k: string]`, And even though JavaScript converts object keys to strings at the end, Typescript is not happy with my code.

How can I convert a `number` type into a string? just like we have a `.toString()` function in JavaScript.

Comment: Error causes: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808160/keyof-inferring-string-number-when-key-is-only-a-string and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76523267/typescript-is-it-true-that-there-is-no-difference-between-key-string-any

Comment: Why not use `[key: UseXQueryPattern<string>]` directly? It’s not like `keyof Endpoints` knows about specific literal keys; it’s just `string | number`. There are ways to turn numeric literal types into corresponding string literal types, but your example code doesn’t need it; just use `string`.  If that doesn’t suffice, please [edit] to provide a [mre] that actually demonstrates a situation that needs such a conversion (e.g., generic keys or a list of literal keys instead of an index signature)